# awk input field seperator and print all variables surrounded by double quotes

Tags: shell

I have a variable in format "world,asia,india" the length of variable is not constant and changes. What I want is I want to format the variable as below.

> "world" , "asia" , "india"

```
echo $variable | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } { $1 = $1; print }'
```

no change in the variable

```
echo $variable | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } { $1 = $1; print }'
```

no change in the variable

input:

> "world,asia,india"
>   "earth,world,europe,france"

output:

> "world" , "asia" , "india"
>
> "earth", "world" , "europe" , "france"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't do it by tunning the `OFS`, because you still have to handle the first and last fields. Just go through all fields and wrap them with quotes. Straightforward:

```
awk -v q='"' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(x=1;x<=NF;x++)$x=q $x q}7'
```

The above line will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a search-and-replace problem than a field separator problem:

```
awk '{gsub(/,/, "\",\""); print}'
# or
sed 's/,/","/g'
```

I'm assuming your input actually has leading and trailing quotes already, and you only need to change the "inner" commas.

Answer (score 0):

I really like @Kent answer.

I suggest we can allow the `awk` to do the parsing with `$1=$1`

```
 echo $variable | awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\",\""}{$1=$1}1'
```